# pgvector , VGG , image vector - dimensions

Tags: postgresql, feature-extraction, dimension, vgg-net, pgvector

I'm using python to get the image vector.
By VGG I receives a 4096 elements vector (float).

```
[0.00e+00 0.00e+00 0.0e+00 0.00e+00 ... 0.00e+00 5.27714975e-02 0.00e+00]
```

I want to save this vector in the database (Postgres) and such for a similar images (pgvector). pgvector documentation say:

```
"Vectors with up to 2,000 dimensions can be indexed."
```

Is my python output a "4096 dimensions" vector or it is "4096 elements - one dimension" vector?
Do I need reduce it up to 2000 or its ok like this?